# Choose the highest row value of an array

Tags: r

I have the following matrix as the result of a neuralnetowrk classification.

```
           [,1]         [,2]         [,3]         [,4]
78 6.679997e-04 4.650186e-05 9.820879e-01 4.037018e-02
85 6.721164e-05 4.037081e-03 3.442273e-04 9.993829e-01
97 5.889365e-06 8.632577e-03 7.168499e-04 9.992764e-01
52 2.118997e-01 5.272690e-04 9.340079e-01 2.318471e-05
63 1.630762e-05 2.278233e-04 9.999697e-01 1.327665e-05
11 9.999995e-01 8.570293e-04 1.033523e-05 1.954824e-03
4  9.999998e-01 4.675230e-03 4.100173e-06 1.386167e-04
67 8.230676e-08 3.901855e-05 9.999998e-01 2.482015e-05
82 3.113818e-05 4.045431e-03 4.980008e-04 9.994791e-01
59 2.199707e-02 8.932616e-05 9.996509e-01 3.201505e-06
68 6.396933e-05 3.507847e-05 9.999431e-01 2.231336e-04
50 3.644305e-03 9.955089e-01 6.152610e-07 2.438749e-03
65 2.985633e-01 3.111180e-04 7.284095e-04 9.567911e-01
84 8.953203e-08 2.043904e-03 2.796990e-02 9.997651e-01
33 5.182628e-03 9.959819e-01 1.582604e-07 9.150829e-03
29 4.094475e-03 9.936016e-01 2.439294e-07 1.378562e-02
21 9.999986e-01 2.920500e-03 2.343490e-04 8.551598e-06
79 2.356930e-01 1.064989e-04 9.998469e-01 8.037159e-08
54 9.760921e-07 1.125948e-04 9.999947e-01 4.913316e-05
71 7.575290e-05 1.901314e-03 9.998013e-01 1.212056e-06
73 3.069030e-02 1.351355e-04 9.961720e-01 2.970879e-05
98 1.852377e-05 1.071308e-02 1.508556e-03 9.923317e-01
8  9.999967e-01 1.091833e-03 8.615699e-05 3.788923e-04
55 7.353873e-05 1.572100e-04 9.999848e-01 2.654150e-06
87 6.485545e-05 1.801804e-03 2.487318e-03 9.978182e-01
66 1.075623e-04 9.965178e-05 9.999943e-01 1.090936e-06
6  9.999996e-01 2.057387e-03 5.199279e-06 8.711600e-04
46 1.675466e-03 9.923240e-01 5.403372e-07 1.406461e-02
48 2.897351e-03 9.948545e-01 2.023942e-07 1.650545e-02
28 4.179047e-03 9.950091e-01 1.261037e-07 2.139333e-02
99 6.191239e-08 2.242249e-02 7.910123e-04 9.999195e-01
47 1.265915e-03 9.928326e-01 1.905755e-07 6.175589e-02
41 2.460404e-02 9.910379e-01 2.134886e-07 6.080052e-03
45 1.416097e-03 9.904895e-01 4.379419e-07 3.060463e-02
18 9.999999e-01 2.119948e-03 4.377037e-06 2.702198e-04
```

What I want to do is to get the highest value in each row. More precisely, I want a vector with the list of the highest values for all the columns.

The first case would be number3:

```
78 6.679997e-04 4.650186e-05 **9.820879e-01** 4.037018e-02
```

*The values represent the probability of correctly choosing the label of a case given the data.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want the column index of the `max` value per row, just use `max.col`

```
max.col(m1, "first")
```

Or with `apply`

```
apply(m1, 1, which.max)
```

---

Inorder to get the `max` values, we can use `apply` with `MARGIN = 1` to loop over the rows and get the `max`

```
apply(m1, 1, max)
```

For columns, use `MARGIN = 2`

```
apply(m1, 2, max)
```

---

A vectorized option is `max.col` to get the max value per row

```
m1[cbind(seq_len(nrow(m1)), max.col(m1, "first")]
```

Or with `pmax` if it is a `data.frame`

```
do.call(pmax, as.data.frame(m1))
```

Comment: @SharkCaller You want the column index or the values.  The expected output showed seems to be the value

Comment: Thx! But that gives a vector of the highest values, what I want is the vector of the columns to which they belong. Edit: Thats right! the output is the value, thats why I want to select the max value, to get it´s index

Comment: @SharkCaller in that case, it is `max.col(m1, "first")`